# Approach checking to show that in case of general compositon of functions the below fact is true under one condition

Tags: functions

I have seen most books give this fact $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to Z$ and $g\circ f : X \to Z$ is surjective , then it surely implies g is surjective.
Consider a more general case of $f:X \to Y$ and $g:W \to Z$ and that $g\circ f : X \to Z $ is surjective then if $g$ is also surjective then on what conditions must be imposed on $f[X] ,Y$ and $W$ such that its always true.

> My thinking if $Y = W $ then its true from the fact i said earlier . Now consider $Y$ $\ne$ $W$ in that case i think if we have $f[X] \subseteq W$ , then we can set $A$ = $f[X]$ $\cap$ $W$ and then $f:X \to A$ and $g:A \to Z$ satisfies the earlier fact and hence this too is surjective ? So the only condition needed is $f[X] \subseteq W$  is this correct  ?

Comment: Use `g \circ f` to to typset $g \circ f$, and `X \to Y` to typset $X \to Y$.

Comment: Edited @angryavian thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one writes "$f: X \to Y$" it does not necessarily imply that $f$ is surjective onto $Y$. So the first sentence is already general, since $f(X)$ might not be all of $Y$.

But if you insist on using your more general setup, you are correct that we only need $f(X) \subseteq W$. But this is automatically given, since it is a requirement in order to define $g \circ f$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing , although i think we can have a case for gof which has domain to be a subset of X , not full domain of X in some cases where we do not have all f[X] to be a subset of W isnt Sir ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax Typically we define the domains and codomains of $f: X \to Y$ and $g : W \to Z$ such that $Y=W$ before even writing down the composition $g \circ f$. By requiring this before defining the composition, we avoid the case described in your comment where $f(X) \not\subseteq W$.